# Incompatible error while using owasp ESAPI encodeForSQL method to protect SQL injection with Codec MYSQL

Tags: sql, security, code-injection, owasp, esapi

Trying to deal with sql injection vulnerability using owasp ESAPI encodeForSQL method to protect SQL injection with Codec MYSQL with the following code

here parameter string value is the sql to be mitigatetd

private String mitigateSQLI(String value) {

```
    Encoder instance = ESAPI.encoder();
    Codec c = new MySQLCodec(MySQLCodec.Mode.STANDARD);

 return instance.encodeForSQL(c, value);
```

service build failed with  incompatible types: org.owasp.esapi.codecs.MySQLCodec cannot be converted to org.owasp.esapi.codecs.Codec // at return statement

Tried altering Codec instance  as  below

private String mitigateSQLI(String value) {

```
    Encoder instance = ESAPI.encoder();
    MySQLCodec c = new MySQLCodec(MySQLCodec.Mode.STANDARD);

 return instance.encodeForSQL(c, value);
```

doesn't help with incompatibility at return statement though

Note: mavn dependency used for Codec

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.owasp.esapi/esapi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Error logs:

```
.java:[90,34] incompatible types: org.owasp.esapi.codecs.MySQLCodec cannot be converted to org.owasp.esapi.codecs.Codec
14:53:33  [INFO] 1 error

 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:53:33  [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
14:53:33  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:53:33  [INFO] Total time:  01:59 min
14:53:33  [INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-13T09:23:32Z
14:53:33  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Compilation failure

ScriptExecutor.java:[90,34] incompatible types: org.owasp.esapi.codecs.MySQLCodec cannot be converted to org.owasp.esapi.codecs.Codec
14:53:33  [ERROR] 
14:53:33  [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
14:53:33  [ERROR]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may be because `Codec` is actually `Codec<Character>`. (See https://javadoc.io/static/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.5.2.0/org/owasp/esapi/codecs/MySQLCodec.html for details.)

The way we have it in our JUnit tests, which seems to work, would be to change:

```
        MySQLCodec c = new MySQLCodec(MySQLCodec.Mode.STANDARD);
```

to:

```
        Codec c = new MySQLCodec(MySQLCodec.Mode.STANDARD);
```

Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Tried that but Issue persisted,although from the same library encodForHTML doesn't seem to be giving any issue.

Comment: I just tried compiling your very first example using openjdk version "1.8.0_362" and it compiles fine on my Linux Mint laptop. What version of Java compiler are you on, what OS are you compiling it on, and what is your *exact* compiler error messages. (All of them.)

Comment: I am using java 11,added error logs in the description. Also tried parsing using jsqlParser queryStatement = CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(queryString);  this approach works for all sql string except 'Create database'

Comment: Okay, That is useful information. We don't generally test with Java 11 because mvn gives an obtuse warning (even for 'mvn clean'), but I just it and it compiles and executes the test src/test/java/org//owasp/esapi/codecsMySQLCodecTest.java just fine (although it is using Java 8 for source and target). Will investigate further and get back to you. Ping me in a few days if I haven't replied by then.

Comment: I am unable to get it to fail using:

openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
o

even with source / target set to '11' (1.11 doesn't work). Please email me or open a Q&A Discussion at https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/discussions/categories/q-a

Comment: Kevin, seems like our external library already had that dependency( esapi1.3.1) whose jar had only CODEC, no MYSQLCODEC implementation was present in that jar. I added  esapi 2.5.2 whose jar had both CODEC and MYSQLCODEC implemented. Using CODEC and MYSQLCODEC from different versions was causing the incompatibility issue. I have excluded the external library 1.3.1 version. Incompatibility issue seems to be resolved now. Thank you so much for your time and effort Kevin

Comment: @Sakshi - Thanks for the update. Yep, that would do it. ESAPI 1.x is no longer even supported and likely has lots of vulnerabilities, most of which don't even have CVEs associated with them.